# Perl: Using lib from external dir, overriding locally installed one

Tags: perl, package

I have a perl version installed in a **read-only** area, together with some packages, including the package `Verilog-Perl` (read only area means that I **cannot** delete files from this installation, including the packages)

I installed a newer version of `Verilog-Perl` in some external directory, and now I want to use the perl version mentioned above with my **external** `Verilog-Perl` version, instead of the older package that is included in the perl installation directory

I.e.
When I execute `use Verilog::Parser;`, I want the newer version to be loaded

How should I do it?

Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried [`lib`](https://metacpan.org/pod/lib) or [`local::lib`](https://metacpan.org/pod/local::lib)?

Comment: What does it mean? What should I exactly do?

Comment: Did you read the documentation(s)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to just modify your environment to always use the new location without futzing with your scripts, the `PERLLIB` environment variable is your friend.

A script to dump the include list:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w
use Data::Dumper;
print Dumper(@INC);
```

Here's my @INC initially:

```
$VAR1 = '/usr/local/lib64/perl5';
$VAR2 = '/usr/local/share/perl5';
$VAR3 = '/usr/lib64/perl5/vendor_perl';
$VAR4 = '/usr/share/perl5/vendor_perl';
$VAR5 = '/usr/lib64/perl5';
$VAR6 = '/usr/share/perl5';
$VAR7 = '.';
```

Now I'll modify it and run the program again:

```
export PERLLIB="/home/mhkohne/lib"

$VAR1 = '/home/mhkohne/lib';
$VAR2 = '/usr/local/lib64/perl5';
$VAR3 = '/usr/local/share/perl5';
$VAR4 = '/usr/lib64/perl5/vendor_perl';
$VAR5 = '/usr/share/perl5/vendor_perl';
$VAR6 = '/usr/lib64/perl5';
$VAR7 = '/usr/share/perl5';
$VAR8 = '.';
```

I'm on a Linux system, and I run the bash shell, you'll need to modify that environment set appropriately for your system.

Answer (score 1):

Use [`lib`](http://perldoc.perl.org/lib.html) to modify your `@INC`.

```
use lib '/path_to_your_new_src';
use Verilog::Parser;

# Confirm where perl pulled your module from:
print $INC{"Verilog/Parser.pm"}, "\n";
```

Answer (score 0):

You will need to manipulate the `@INC` special variable to do this. As per [the documentation](http://perldoc.perl.org/lib.html#Adding-directories-to-@INC), it will check each directory for modules in order. You can prioritize a certain directory by moving it to the front of the list temporarily. For example:

```
BEGIN {
    unshift @INC, "/some/other/dir/";
    require Some::Module;
    shift @INC;
}
```